# Blue Screen stop code 0x00000024

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I did recently downloaded windows 8 in my C drive (windows installation) and then extracted in c drive also and it made my c drive out of space. then i cleaned my C drive and made almost 3 G.B space in it and shutdown my computer.

Next morning it didn't started. I have been looking on **stop codes** but no luck yet. Can you tell me what does mean the four codes in the braces
I tried a number of things

```
Chkdsk/F --> No Errors Found
safe mode --> not starting in safe mode
```

stop code 0x00000024 is something related to ntfs file system

Below is the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detailed description of [0x24 stop code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I don't think that parameters description will help you solve your problem. First number is encoded information about source file and line number where error happened in ntfs.sys driver. Second and third numbers are pointers to memory, so they are useless for you too.

You ran `chkdsk /f`, try to run `chkdsk /r`, which will scan your drive for bad sectors.

If you can plug this disk to a computer with working Windows, you may try to examine Windows logs from this disk. For this, open Event Viewer and there select Action->Open Saved Logs... then select `Applications.evtx` or `System.evtx` from `X:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`, where `X` is the letter assigned to your disk.